# WooCommerce - Display more than one variation name as product name in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I would like to replace the name of the product in the shopping cart with two selected variants. Ideally in this format:

Variant 1 - Variant 2

With the following code it works, but only shows the name of the first variant.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_items_prices', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_items_prices( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        $original_name = method_exists( $product, 'get_name' ) ? $product->get_name() : $product->post->post_title;

        $new_name = wc_gzd_get_product( $product )->get_attribute('pa_attribute3';

        if( method_exists( $product, 'set_name' ) )
            $product->set_name( $new_name );
        else
            $product->post->post_title = $new_name;
    }
}
```

Does anyone find the bug or have a way how it works?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it.

I take the code above to use attribute 3 as the item name and add attribute 1 and 2 with this code:

```
    function show_things_in_cart_items( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        $att1 = $product->get_attribute('pa_attribute1');
        $att2 = $product->get_attribute('pa_attribute2');

        {
            $item_name = '<class="product-model">' . $att1 . __( " ", "woocommerce") . $att2 . __( " - ", "woocommerce") . $item_name;
        } 

        return $item_name;
    }

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'show_things_in_cart_items', 99, 3 );
```

Thanks to User [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec) for the base of this code, i just modified it for my needs.
I found it here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/348631/adding-product-sku-before-cart-item-name-in-woocommerce